# Обход заблокированных слов

Tags: администрирование, сервисы

Есть какие-то сервисы?

Которые могут генерировать список слов, из указанного слова.

Допустим я добавил в **черный список** слово `Текст`.
И пользователь решит обойти систему, начнет изменять символы в слове, на Английские символы, спец символы, и на другие возможные.

Comment: **Х**итрый **У**частник **И**звернется **Т**ак **А**ригинально, что никакие чёрные списки не помогут

Comment: @andreymal, Номад, перелогиньтесь.